# How to condense columns and copy them into another worksheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I have data across multiple excel files that looks like this:
[image]

I want to collapse column B so that it just lists the numbers with no spaces between them and removes column C. I also need column L to move to column J and remove the empty spaces so it look identical to columnn B.

This is what the final solution looks like:

[image]

So far I have been copy and pasting and then searching for blank cells and deleting them. I am having trouble writing a code because the amount of data in each category and spaces between them change on every file. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please see how to [ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through and delete rows with something like below. You'll have to adapt it four categories with multiple choice to move the x to the right row.

```
Sub FormatCollapse()

For i = 1 to 1000
    If IsEmtpy(Range("A" & i ).Value) And IsEmtpy(Range("B" & i ).Value) Then
        Rows(i).delete
    End If
Next

End sub
```

You can use this same concept to loop across columns and sheets

Comment: You might be able to add a line of code to use the worksheet function COUNTA to see if there is an x ( greater than 1 value) in a row with lettered options to see what answer was chosen.